# RecyclerView containing collapsible TextViews ("show more" / "show less")

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In my android app, I have a RecyclerView that contains TextViews. If the text in the TextView is longer than three lines,only in that case, I want to add an option to expand/collapse the TextView.

I have gone through suggested solutions, with normal textview (getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener, also booleans) also with external libraries too. I tried, but I ended up with no result. It would be very helpful if someone could share a code example or give suggestions for it (specially to achieve above in 'Recyclerview'). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

**Theory**

Step 1. Using MVVM architecture, you can store 2 variables `LiveData<List<*>>` in a `ViewModel`.

`completeDataList` = Store complete list of data.

`shownDataList` = List of data you want to show in `RecyclerView`. You'll play with this list (to add or to delete).

Step 2. In your `Fragment`, get a `ViewModel` and observe those `shownDataList`. Whenever the value changed, use `RecyclerView.notifyDataSetChanged()` to refresh your `RecyclerView`.

Step 3. Use `TextView.onClickListener` to give command to add / delete contents `shownDataList` from `completeDataList`.

**Sample Code**

Disclaimer: This is just a sample code to show roughly how it's done.

MyViewModel.kt

```
class MyViewModel: ViewModel() {

    val completeDataList = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()
    val shownDataList = MutableLiveData<List<String>>()

    fun initData() {
        //fill your completeDataList with all data
        //Copy three lines to shownDataList
    }

    fun showAll() {
        //Clear and Fill your shownDataList with all data from completeDataList
    }

    fun showLess() {
        //Put only 3 data in your shownDataList
    }
}
```

MyActivity.kt

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    //After setting the layout, 
    //And also already initialise the RecyclerView along with it's adapter

    myVM = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MyViewModel::class.java)
    myVM.shownDataList.observe(this, Observer { newList ->
         if (newList is List<*>) {
             //renewData here is just setting newList 
             //and call notifyDataSetChanged()
             recyclerAdapter.renewData(newList)
         }
    })
    textView.setOnClickListener {
         if (allShown) {
             myVM.showLess()
             allShown = false
         } else {
             myVM.showAll()
             allShown = true
         }
    }
}
```

Hope it works! :)

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I am new to MVVM pattern and text for textview is dynamic. text may be of 10 lines. At app launch , text will appear only of 3 lines with 'view more' appending string. As soon as user clicks on 'view more' , whole 10 lines text will be visible with 'view less' appending string.

Comment: MVVM pattern is very useful to build reactive android app. That way, you change the UI whenever there's changes in the data. And I think it will exactly fill your needs. On step 3, whenever someone click the `TextView`, just copy everything to your `shownDataList`. That way your `shownDataList` shows whole 10 lines.

Comment: sure. let me try this solution. I will look forward to MVVM pattern as well. If you have code example of above with MVVM let me know.